# Unable to change button image when pressed inside a UITableViewCell in iOS application

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableViewController that contains a table, whose cells I wish to add a button to.  This is a customized button that will act as a checkbox, with an image that it has for its normal state, and another image that it has when the user selects it.  Unfortunately, the image is not changing state whenever I press it, and for some reason, it is also not calling the target method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    TestObject *tObject = [myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = tObject.testTitle;

    testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [testButton setFrame:CGRectMake(280, 57, 25, 25)];
    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [testButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CheckBox2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [testButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(clickOnCheckButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell addSubview:testButton];

    return cell;

}
```

For the record, I have indeed implemented the method:

```
-(void)clickOnCheckButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"button has been pressed");
}
```

and have made sure the spelling is correct, which is why I don't understand the reason why the method is not being called when the button in each cell is pressed.

The other problem with my table output is that my very first cell does not have a button inside it.  All other cells below it however, do.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: A couple of things you might like to investigate: a table cell has a contentView property for all Cell contents, you might like to try adding your button to the cells contentView instead of the cell. Also you might like to replace the cell's accessoryView with your button.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your suggestion.  The accessoryView helped.  I am now able to successfully load the button on to the cell and call the respective method.  Can you post this as an answer so that I may select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the cell's `accessoryView` property you can set it to a custom view, like your button, and it's designed to act like a button. You then have the option to use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `– tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` to control the action.

Answer (score 0):

you are write the flowing code in our project

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    ObjectiveCcustTcell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   ObjctiveString *temp=[_arraymain objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.labQutionNo.text=temp.qutNO;
    cell.labQution.text=temp.qution;
    cell.labAns.text=temp.ans;
    cell.labAns2.text=temp.ans2;
    cell.labAns3.text=temp.ans3;

[cell.ButAns1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp.ansD1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.ButAns2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp.ansD2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.ButAns3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:temp.ansD3] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     if(indexPath.row==0&&t==1)
        {
             [cell.ButAns1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }

    if(indexPath.row==1&&t==3)
            {

             [cell.ButAns1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }



    [cell.ButAns1 addTarget:self action:@selector(MEthodBut:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.ButAns2 addTarget:self action:@selector(MEthodBut2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [cell.ButAns3 addTarget:self action:@selector(MEthodBut3:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [cell.ButAns1 setTag:indexPath.row];
     [cell.ButAns2 setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.ButAns3 setTag:indexPath.row];

    return cell;



}


-(void)MEthodBut:(UIButton *)sender
{

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int row = (int)button.tag;





    if(row==0)
    {

        t=1;

[_tablemain reload];

    }
}
```